# Wordpress Starter Kit

Tags: wordpress, installation

I'm familiar with Drupal / Drush / [Civicrm Starter Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_starterkit) but is there a Starter Kit or sample theme for Wordpress?  I've used [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) and stumbled on [civicrm wp-cli](https://github.com/andy-walker/wp-cli-civicrm) but basically looking for a quick start to customize...

Answer (score 1):

Try just using the regular installation process--it should be simple enough.  You won't find or want to work with a different theme for the backend of CiviCRM, and on the front, you should find that CiviCRM works well in most cases.

Now in 4.6, CiviCRM will set up a base page for you, so it's one step easier, too.